# dark mode implementation crashing on a real device, but not on a virtual device

Tags: android, android-theme, android-dark-theme

I am defined theme change inside a list preference as (inflated in SettingsActivity):

```
 <ListPreference
        app:defaultValue="default"
        app:entries="@array/themes_labels"
        app:entryValues="@array/themes_color"
        app:key="@string/Theme"
        app:useSimpleSumm"theme"
        app:title=aryProvider="true" />
  </PreferenceCategory>
```

and the arraus are defined as:

```
<resources>
  <array name="themes_labels">
    <item>"Default"</item>
    <item>"Light"</item>
    <item>"Dark"</item>
  </array>

  <string-array name="themes_color">
    <item>"Default"</item>
    <item>"Light"</item>
    <item>"Dark"</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

Now, though I tried to follow [dark theme developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme), I did not understand variables like `configuration.uiMode`, and hence I have implemented as (in MainActivity):

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
      AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
    } else{
      AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY);
    }
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    String theme = sharedPref.getString("theme", "Default");
//    Toast.makeText(this, theme, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (theme.equals("Dark")){
      AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    }else if (theme.equals("Light")){
      AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    } else{
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
      } else{
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY);
      }
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
```

While this is working fine on a emulator, in my real device, it is crashing abruptly. 
But, as I dont have any way to see what is going wrong, I dont have any clue.

Can anybody kindly help?

Comment: please add your crashlog/stacktrace

Comment: What device? Have you tried on multiple devices? Newer features like this are sometimes implemented incorrectly by some manufacturers.

Comment: @TooMany, as I have said, it is crashing on real device, and I don't have a way to see what's going wrong, can you please explain the point of your comment? Either explain how I can check the crash log or.. Oh, I guess you haven't read till the end.

Comment: @jack, its Mi A3, a android one mobile

Comment: @BaRud How don't you have a way to see what's going wrong? It's normal to retrieve crash logs from physical devices. You could get the relevant portion by following along in Android Studio's LogCat. Or you can just connect the device to your computer and run `adb logcat`.

Comment: since you dont have logs of what the issue is then you're truly shooting in the dark. it could be a user issue, or a device missing a feature, or you may need to rewrite your whole app.
no logs, or no replication = no idea on what to fix..pretty simple